# Creating sub arrays from 1D array - Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have searched the Internet to try and find a solution and have tried to make my own but can't seem to figure it out.

I need to be able to take a 1D NumPy array and within that array, after every 1024 values they get turned into a 32x32 array and keep going until the initial array has been completely searched through and to avoid any errors simply append any zeros necessary to fill up the sub-arrays.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please provide some small example that could be tested on. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelSidorov. Why not just `np.random.rand(N)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to do much. First pad the array to the nearest multiple of 1024:

```
arr = np.random.rand(1024 * 5 - 100)

pad = -arr.size % 1024
if pad:
    arr = np.concatenate((arr, np.zeros(pad, dtype=arr.dtype)))
```

Then reshape into an array of shape `(N, 32, 32)`:

```
imgs = arr.reshape(-1, 32, 32)
```

Now you have a stack of images. Indexing `imgs` or iterating over it will give you the individual `(32, 32)` images.